# Highlight Color 1 doesnt change in Joomla template

Tags: button, joomla, colors, highlight

I changed the color of 'Highlight Color 1' in joomla. But the color on the website is now just black and not the color I've chosen or even the color it was before. See the image for the example. At the top of the image is the color I've chosen in Joomla. At the bottom is the button on the webpage which just highlights in black.[image] What can I do to have the color I've chosen or maybe the default color?

Comment: Try adding a semicolon after the color.

Comment: No it didn't work. I now found out what the default color was en when I enter that color it also won't change back into the default color.

Comment: It's fixed. You did send me at the right track. I had to remove the hashtag